# Controlling the Camera's Auto-Exposure 

Tags: android, android-camera

I have written a camera app in android and I have tested it on two android phones, on one phone the auto-exposure works well when previewing but on the other phone it doesn't work at all. The first phone only works when I call the autoFocus() method. On the latter phone, the build-in app's auto-exposure works but not my code. Is there any method that can start use the auto-exposure manually?

Comment: do you want to control auto exposure or auto focus?

Answer (score 0):

Check [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) class

```
Camera.Parameters   getParameters()
```

and check these two methods in Camera.Parameters class

```
int getExposureCompensation()
```

Gets the current exposure compensation index.

```
float   getExposureCompensationStep()
```

Gets the exposure compensation step.

You should check the capabilities of camera of the phone before assuming existence of certain function